# SyntaxError: Invalid character in identifier when importing models generated using sqlacodegen

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I am auto-generating tables in postgresql and models are autogenerated using `sqlacodegen` using names from a list.

Some of the names are non-ascii characters. For name `aussieBabe` which created a table `aussieBabe_index` for which sqlAlchemy model is `aussieBabeIndex`. but when I try to import these models for querying I get below error.

```
line 147
    class aussieBabeIndex(Base):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I assume that this can be solved by removing invalid characters before creating the table or restricting the class name. I want to restrict the class name which is generated by `sqlacodegen`, how can i achieve this? or can I set Unicode encoding for code?

Comment: post a bug to the issue tracker!

Comment: If you can't wait for a bugfix, changing `_re_invalid_identifier` in https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/blob/master/sqlacodegen/codegen.py might be useful; or maybe even run it under Python2 to avoid unicode characters in identifiers altogether.

Comment: Will post bug report, for now I will follow @snakecharmerb suggestion to change `_re_invalid_identifier`

Comment: @Harwee actually, are you sure you're running the same version? the regular expression `\W` *does match* `` so these should be removed...

Comment: Yes, those should be removed manually, but I have too many names with such problems, I need to create a mapping to dynamically point new classes, but anyway sqlacodegen should atleast raise an error instead of writing invalid chars which is handled by `_re_invalid_identifier` i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name contains some characters which not even Python 3 will allow. You need to fix the class name by hand. SQLACodegen cannot be expected to produce perfect results, as its documentation states too.